# How do I change a custom woocommerce checkbox label programmatically?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkbox

I have this custom checkbox in the checkout page:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'checkout_shipping_form_packing_addition', 20);
function checkout_shipping_form_packing_addition()
{
    $domain = 'woocommerce';
    echo '<tr class="packing-select";>' . __('', $domain) . '<td>';

    $chosen   = WC()->session->get('chosen_packing');

    // Add a custom checkbox field
    $variable = <<<XYZ
<html>
<body>
 <p style="font-size:15px; margin-top: -38px; margin-left: 5px; height:auto; border:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#FF0000; padding: 20px;"><b>Consegna rapida?</b></p>
</body>
</html>
XYZ;
    woocommerce_form_field('chosen_packing', array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide packing'),
        'label'     => __($variable, 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => false,
    ), $chosen);

    echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

I want the label to change when it's checked, so I tried adding this

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process2');
 
function my_custom_checkout_field_process2() {
    global $woocommerce;
 
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if (isset($_POST['chosen_packing'])){
        
        $_POST['chosen_packing']['label'] = 'no';
    
        }
}
```

But it doesn't work, and I'm not sure how to proceed exactly.
I need the label to change whenever the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need some clarifications.
Do you want the label to change when you check the checkbox or do you want it to be changed when the page loaded and the user checked it before?

If you want to change a label when the user clicks on the checkbox, you should use JavaScript.
With PHP, you can do it when the page has been reloaded.
So here's a JS code that will change the label to 'no' when the user clicks on the checkbox.
Also, you don't need 'my_custom_checkout_field_process2' function.

Give the `<b>` tag an id. (I gave it id="the_label") and add the script in your script file (recommended) or add it after `<body>` in your code (not recommended).

```
<script>
        function labelChanger(){
            if (jQuery('#chosen_packing:checked')){
                jQuery('#the_label').html('no');
            }
        }

        jQuery('#chosen_packing').click(function (){
            labelChanger();
        });

    </script>
```

I hope it helps you. If you didn't get the answer, give me some clarifications.

Comment: TY it's working!!
However when I uncheck it the label stays the same, I tried adding "else jQuery('#the_label').html('yes');" after the ('no'); but it's not changing it

Comment: Ok managed to make it work but I had to change it significantly, this is the new code that works:


<script>
jQuery('#the_label').html('text');  //this sets the starting label
    
function labelChanger(){
            
    if (jQuery('#chosen_packing').prop("checked") == false) {
              jQuery('#the_label').html('text');
          } 
    else {
              jQuery('#the_label').html('text');
    }
}

jQuery('#chosen_packing').change(function (){
    labelChanger();
});        
</script>